# Recorrer loop y rellanar select con datos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde creo un `switch` de acuerdo a una cantidad x de codigos de productos. El primer while me funciona bien ya que me trae los codigos. Al momento de ingresar al case este `AJAX` tambien funciona puedo ver la data por `Network`

Aqui el problema tengo una variable `newOptions` que es un array de datos.
En el result de `AJAX` este quiero recorrerlo y llenarlo con los datos. Para luego este llenar otro select con mas datos

```
 $("#producto").change(function() {
            var valor = $(this).val(); // Capturamos el valor del select
            var texto = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); // Capturamos el texto del option seleccionado

            switch (valor) {
                <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt)) { ?>

                case <?php   echo "'".$row["c_codigo_producto"]."'";   ?>:
                    $("#divhidden").first().show("fast", function() {});
                      var newOptions = {};
                    $.ajax({
                        data: {
                            'valor': valor
                        },
                        url: 'JSON/search_group.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {


                          $.each(data, function() {index, row){
                            var code = row.c_codigo_group;
                            var name = row.c_group;
                            alert(name);
                            }
                         });

                       newOptions = { //Ejemplo como deberia quedar el newOptions
                          "FINO": "01",
                          "LEÑA": "02",
                          "PELLETS": "03",
                          "TRITURADO": "04",
                      };

                          },
                        async: false,
                    });


                    var $el = $('#subgrupo');
                    $el.html(' ');
                    $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
                        $el.append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value", value).text(key));
                    });

                    break;
                    <?php } ?>
            }

        });
```

MI PHP

```
<?php
include_once('../include/conexion.php');

$valor = trim($_POST['valor']);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM c_group
  WHERE c_codigo_producto =  '$valor'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conexion2, $query);
  $output = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {

   $output[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($output,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: no se entiende bien, queres rellenar el array `newOptions` con la respuesta de la peticion ?

Comment: si, con la data que obtengo del ajax

Answer (score 0):

puede ser por que lo recorres fuera de la funcion ajax deberia estar dentro del success

ya que como lo tienes recorre inmediatamente  $.each(newOptions sin esperar a que te de respuesta la petición ajax

ejemplo:

```
 $.ajax({
                        data: {
                            'valor': valor
                        },
                        url: 'JSON/search_group.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {


                          $.each(data, function() {index, row){
                            var code = row.c_codigo_group;
                            var name = row.c_group;
                            alert(name);
                            }
                         });

                       newOptions = { //Ejemplo como deberia quedar el newOptions
                          "FINO": "01",
                          "LEÑA": "02",
                          "PELLETS": "03",
                          "TRITURADO": "04",
                      };
                      var $el = $('#subgrupo');
                      $el.html(' ');
                      $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
                      $el.append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value", value).text(key));
                      });

                          },
                        async: false,
                    });
```

espero haber entendido tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

para rellenar el array necesitas usar la funcion `.push()` que te permite de inserir datos en el array :

ejemplo :

```js
var newOptions = [];

newOptions.push({"nombre": "pedro"});
newOptions.push({"apellido": "suarez"});

console.log(newOptions)
```

logicamente, utilizando la estructura de tu JSON para insertar los dato deseados.

espero que te sea de ayuda, exitos !

**EDIT**

ejemplo con tu codigo :

```
success: function(data) {
   $.each(data, function() {index, row){
      var code = row.c_codigo_group;
      var name = row.c_group;
     newOptions.push({ name : code }); // este quedaria como el ejemplo que pusiste, en caso cambias de lugar las variables

// o simplemente en una sola operacion : 
newOptions.push({ row.c_group : row.c_codigo_group });
  }
}
```

Comment: en mi foreach de ajax yo quiero agregarle data al array

Comment: @MoteCL por eso en el foreach agregas `newOptions.push({ code: name }) ` y el array se rellena con los datos resultantes de la peticion ajax

Comment: el `each()` me tirar un error

Comment: que error te da ?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: es porque tiene una parentesis `)` de mas o de menos ..

Comment: hay un `{`en vez de un `(` . Busque otra forma de recorrer el foreach   `$.each(data, function() {});` y me muestra este error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` :( gracias x tu ayuda